# Sync AWS file that isn't done being transferred

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What happens if I try to do `aws sync` from an s3 file that is still being transferred?  Will `aws sync` realize the file is changing and do a proper sync?

Comment: `Will rysnc realize` - not sture what you mean by `rysnc` here. You meant performing simultaneous/concurrent `aws sync` on the same file? If yes, my answer applies, otherwise I'll have to update it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between aws sync and rysnc is.  Not sure if all from one apply to other.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple syncs running at the same time, the last one to transfer a specific file will always overwrite the corresponding destination file. The [aws s3 sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) should implement a locking mechanism if it wants to avoid this behaviour - simultaneous transfer of the same file - but it currently does not (as of the date of this answer).

Quoting the official [REST API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html):

> Amazon S3 is a distributed system. **If it receives multiple write
>   requests for the same object simultaneously, it overwrites all but the
>   last object written.** Amazon S3 does not provide object locking; if you
>   need this, make sure to build it into your application layer or use
>   versioning instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the source file was the one that was changing

Comment: No problem. I did update my answer to clarify. Hope it helps.